# Disable .phony for one target in Make

Tags: makefile

I'm using a .phony target to create a configuration file before running most targets in my Makefile.  However there is one target, the init: target, that should not run the .phony (because it is initializing the directory and the needed file does not exist.)

Is there a way to disable the .phony target for this one target but have it work for any other target in the makefile?

Comment: I solved this problem in my case by adding a dependency to the target referenced by .PHONY.  This dependency copied the file I needed.  I still wonder if there is an answer to the question, though.

Comment: It would be easier to discuss this if you told us the name of the phony target; I'll call it `config`. Do you not want `config` to be a prerequisite of `init`? What is the "needed file", and what needs it?